# Start in Emergency mode

Tags: boot, recovery-mode, pcie

My computer starts in emergency mode. My processor is AMD Rysen Threadripper 1950x. I am on Ubuntu 16.4 LTS.
These error lines keep printing on the terminal:

```
[ 3276.313138] pcieport 0000:00:01.1 PCI Bus Error: severity:Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0009(Receiver ID)

[ 3276.313768] pcieport 0000:00:01.1 device [1022:1453] error xtatu/mask=00000080/00006000

[ 3276.314401] pcieport 0000:00:01.1 [ 7] Bad DLLP
```

And I cannot find the files within my home directory. That is, I can go to my home directory, cd /home/joe, and there are directories within, but everything is empty!
I have my operating system on /dev/mven0n1p1. But my home is on (I believe sda, sdb, sdc, and sdd). I have those 4 drives in Raid 10. If remember them to be collectively named md1.
I tried

```
mount /dev/md1 /mnt

mount special device /dev/md1 does not exist
```

Backstory. My computer died some months ago - it started crashing intermittently, then crashed every five minutes. I finally analyses the problem being a faulty water-based cpu cooler. I just replaced that and my temperature is now under control. However, I am stuck in emergency mode whenever I boot.

journalctl -xb and fdisk printouts are here:
https://gist.github.com/molnarjoe/a721545a7a8ed22daf550c2bdc24c873

Edit:
I found this page with a hint: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400299
I believe my disk name has changed!!! I am mounting a disk on boot which now has a different UID. But I don't know which one it is.
I am including the blkid and fstab printouts at
https://gist.github.com/molnarjoe/09b6339e2dbf25aa387aa68680936a5b

The UID in question is for the /home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be something different. I have 4 X 1TB drives in Raid 10. One of them remained unplugged after putting my box back together after diagnosis. I found the problem by comparing blkid vs. fstab outputs. My UID for a disk on fstab to mount was not on the blkid. And there were only 3 of the 4 disks on blkid.
I poked around the cables until I found the loose one. Now I’m good. Working again.
Strange symptom for an even stranger problem.
Maybe someone can use this lesson.